# Gravitational time dilation derivation

Tags: gravity, time-dilation

One way of deriving gravitational time dilation is to imagine an observer in free fall in some gravitational field passing by two observers stationary in that field. Because inertial observer passes each of them with different speed he observes different time dilation which is just good old STR. We can compare time rates at each point and see it depends on gravitational potential at these points. But, this is all valid for the inertial observer. How come that this is also valid for the stationary observers, that is, how come that one can from this conclude that observer in a lower potential point experiences that the other one, at higher point, has slower time flow? I see it is true by STR for the observer in free fall but what exactly is the argument for this to be true for the two stationary observers in regard to each other?